# Does "which" make this sentence clearer?

Tags: relative-pronouns

As I am proof-reading my own writing, I am not sure if which one of these two sentences sounds clearer.

> Language skill can bring distinct advantages that set those learning it apart from their monolingual peers
>
> Language skill can bring distinct advantages to those learning it, which sets them apart from their monolingual peers

Comment: In the first one, "sets" is wrong because it's a plural subject ("advantages") + a singular verb (sets).  You can't reduce the sentence to "*The advantages sets...*".  In the second one, you have "which" (used as singular) with "sets" (also singular) which sounds much better.

Comment: .. but in the second one, "language skills" is plural, but "it" is singular.

Comment: FYI -  the present participle *setting* works nicely here.  *Language skill can bring distinct advantages to those learning it, setting them apart from their peers.*

Answer (score 1):

The usage of *which vs that* is a common grammatical confusion. A general rule of thumb to remember is :

'Which' is used to provide additional information about the subject but is not necessary ( in a way that it doesn't change the meaning of the sentence ).

For example :

> '*Our office, which has two lunchrooms, is located in Cincinnati*'.

Here, 'which has two lunchrooms' provides an additional information about the office but it doesn't change the fact that it is located in Cincinnati.

Now consider,

> *Our office that has two lunchrooms is located in Cincinnati*.

The usage of 'that' here is a must to point out that we are talking about one of our offices which has two lunchrooms. ( aka restrictive clause )

Another thing to note is :
That refers mostly to things, though a class or type of person is also sometimes referred to by this pronoun:

> “He has the key that fits in this door.”
>
> “This is a team that is going places.”

So technically, the first sentence seems to be more correct to me.

**Sources:**

- [DailyWritingTips.com](https://www.dailywritingtips.com/when-to-use-that-which-and-who/)
- [WritersDigest.com](https://www.writersdigest.com/online-editor/which-vs-that)

Comment: "Which" is perfectly acceptable in integrated relative clauses. Examples like "The film which I needed is not obtainable" is grammatically fine.

Answer (score 0):

Both sentences are acceptable and I would find it hard to find any difference in meaning or clarity between them. If you find the second one clearer, then you should use it.